# Hibernate : add child to parent collection

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate on a web project, which a have two different classes (Node, Interface)

**Node**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="NODES")
public class Node {
    //...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="node", cascade={CascadeType.ALL, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST}, orphanRemoval=true)
    private Set<Interface> interfaces = new HashSet<>();

    //...

}
```

---

**Interface**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="INTERFACES")
public class Interface {
    //...

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="REF_NODE")
    private Node node;

    //...
}
```

---

Everything is fine, 
My question is how can I add an Interface(chlid) to a Node(Parent) that already persisted? means if i already has some Node in the database with 2 Interfaces for exemple and I want to add the third one, how i can do it?

My first quick solution is to use native sql in Hibernate, like this:

```
public void addInteface(Interface i, Long idNode) {
    //OpenSession..
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;

    try {
        //Start transaction
        tx = session.beginTransaction();

        //Native SQL in Hibernate
        SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("INSERT INTO INTERFACES (ID_INTERFACE, ALIAS, ID_NODE) VALUES (NULL, :Alias, :idNode)");

        query.setParameter("ifAlias", i.getAlias());
        query.setParameter("refNode", idNode);
        //Some other parameters...

        //Execute and Commit
        query.executeUpdate();
        tx.commit();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (tx != null) tx.rollback();
        throw e;

    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

It works, but it's not the best solution i believe.

NB: I found some topics here in stackoverflow with the almost same title but didn't answer my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done in 2 ways.

**1st Option:**

```
node.getInterfaces().add(new Interface(....)); // you have orphan removal to true, this will work
session.saveOrUpdate(node);
tx.commit();
session.close();
```

Or

**2nd OPtion**

```
newInterface.setNode(nodeObject);
session.saveOrUpdate(newInterface);
tx.commit();
session.close();
```

In the above 2 methods, 2nd option works great compared to the first one. 1st one will pull all the children when you call getInterfaces(), which does not perform better.

Answer (score 1):

//Syntax may not be on point, also some psuedcode

Lets say you want to add an interface to Node with an id that is 1:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("Select n from Node n where n.id = '1'");//JPQL
Node n = query.getSingleResult();
```

Then you will make a new Interface

```
Interface i = new Interface();
```

Then set the variables to what you want but also set the node

```
i.setVariables(..);
i.setNode(n);
```

Then update

```
session.merge(i);
```

Now all this is assuming generator id is correct and such.

Comment: Thank's for the answer :)